# Unable to find dsound.h after installing Directx 9.0c on Windows XP

Tags: directx

I am trying to build [portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com) using MS VC++ 2009. The first time I tried to do that, I got an error that dsound.h was not found. I then downloaded and installed DirectX 9.0c. Now I assumed that the installer would create an environment variable DX_SDK, through which I can point to the header file in MSVC. However, that did not happen and now I am not able to locate the folder where DirectX is installed. The installer does not provide an option for me to specify where I want to install. Please help.

Comment: The legacy DirectSound8 headers are included in Windows SDK 7.0 or later. You don't need the legacy DirectX SDK for that. See [DirectX SDKs of a certain age](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/08/22/directx-sdk-s-of-a-certain-age.aspx) and [A Brief History of Windows SDKs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/10/03/a-brief-history-of-windows-sdks.aspx). Debugging support for DirectSound on modern versions of Windows is hard to come by, so you'd be better off using WASAPI or XAudio2.

Answer (score 4):

Typically in such cases you need to configure the IDE to search additional include folders. In VS2005 that's done through Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/VC++ Directories, then 'Include files' at the upper right combo. You'd want to manually navigate to the DX include path - for example, on my machine that's 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (August 2008)\Include'.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable created at installation of DirectXSDK is called "DXSDK_DIR". You should be able to find it under the "System Environment Variables" and it's set to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\" as default.